# Rails MInitest. How's the proper way to check if an exception is raised when the Exception class is private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I've defined a "private" exception class in one of my models (since it's an implementation detail) like that:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  class InvalidStateException < StandardError
    def initialize(msg = "Invalid State")
       super(msg)
    end
  end

  private_constant :InvalidStateException
end
```

And in my test I want to check if the exception is being raised like this:

```rb
test "should not follow themselves" do
  joao = users(:joao)

  assert_not joao.following?(joao)
  assert_raise(User::InvalidStateException) { joao.follow(joao) }
  assert_not joao.following?(joao)
end
```

But as expected a NameError is raised once i'm trying to reference a private constant in the test:

```rb
test_should_not_follow_themselves#RelationshipTest (1.92s)
NameError:         NameError: private constant #<Class:0x00005570b89cba48>::InvalidStateException referenced
```

So how can I let the Exception being private and test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing seems counter-intuitive to me, but who am I to judge.

Nothing in ruby is really private, you can get your "private" constant using `.const_get`

```
User.const_get(:InvalidStateException)
```

Comment: All I want is to prevent the clients to use directly the exception class by User::InvalidStateException. There's a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I decided to write the Exception Class inside my other class because it's an implementation detail, so I don't see a reason to create it as a separated class, once i'll only use inside my class (the wrapper). But i'm a new rubist, so I probably doing things in a way that is counter-intuitive in Ruby. There's a pattern for this case in Ruby?

Comment: If you raise a private exception, make sure it's only for internal use and that you always rescue it. If you raise it out of your library, then it's going to be difficult to rescue for others since its private. If it is for internal use only, then it's probably just flow control and often if statements are better.